# How a multiset works and how one can find the minimum element in multiset

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, multiset

When we insert elements in a multiset are they inserted in a sorted order .

How can i find the smallest elements of a mutiset ?

And how can i access ith element in a mutiset ?

Can some one please explain how multiset works and how it store elements in it ?

Thanks in advance  .

Comment: "Are they inserted in a sorted order" - perfectly answerable if you had read its documentation. Seriously, use Google.

Comment: i googled it but was not getting a link which could explain all my doubts clearly thats why i posted it here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution that always works (regardless of the ordering scheme):

```
   std::multiset<int> m;
   //do something with m
   std::cout<<*std::min_element(m.begin(),m.end())<<std::endl;
```

That should be O(n), so it takes no advantages of the already sorted nature of the storage scheme of a multiset.

Access "i-th" element:

```
std::cout<<*std::next(m.begin(),i-1)<<std::endl;
```

But again, what is meant by "i-th element" is determined by your ordering scheme.

---

Ok, and when your ordering scheme is given by `std::less` -- the standard case -- then indeed

```
m.begin();
```

gives you the minimal element. You can read it up [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/?kw=multiset).

Comment: if i am using m.begin() isn't it the pointer to least element of m ?

Comment: That depends on your comparison function, but basically, yes.

Comment: what if i want to erase only one element from a multiset which is occurnig more than one time in a multiset what should i do /

Answer (score 0):

Multiset works by maintaining a [red-black balanced binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Generally the meaning of a balanced tree (and red-black specifically) is that you can add/search/delete/get the min/get the max (and more) in O(logk) operations where k is the size of the tree (that is, the number of elements in the multiset). Specifically in c++'s multiset the complexity might change a bit, depends on the action.

If your set is `s` then:

- You can get the min element in the set by using `s.begin();`
- You can get the i'th element in the set by using `*next(s.begin(),i-1)` (as `next(it, d)` gives you the pointer to the element in position `it + d`). The complexity of this is linear as stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).